# Material UI gap prop is ignored by box-sizing: border-box, Is there a way to force it to not ignore the gap?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI and I have a simple Grid component with three Grids nested inside like this:
[image]

The parent container is a Grid with these props:

```
  <Grid  container component="form" noValidate autoComplete="on" gap={2}>
```

The problem is that by adding gap={2} to the parent the button gets pushed down, though it has box-sizing: border-box;
[image]

This is the default css provided by Material UI:

[image]

It seems that box-sizing is ignoring the gap.
I could force this with flex-wrap: nowrap but there should be a way to have the box-sizing not ignore the gap, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try wrapping your inputs and buttons in `span` or `div` or something?

Something I remember is that inputs and stuff don't always work as expected with the griding system.